# Kube-monkey not terminating pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have nginx deployment object in "chaostesting" namespace with the config shown below,

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: nginx-deployment
      labels:
        app: nginx
        kube-monkey/enabled: "enabled"
        kube-monkey/identifier: "nginx-victim"
        kube-monkey/mtbf: "1"
        kube-monkey/kill-mode: "fixed"
        kube-monkey/kill-value: "1"
    spec:
      replicas: 10
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: nginx
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: nginx
            kube-monkey/enabled: "enabled"
            kube-monkey/identifier: "nginx-victim"
            kube-monkey/mtbf: "1"
            kube-monkey/kill-mode: "fixed"
            kube-monkey/kill-value: "1"
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: nginx
            image: nginx:1.14.2
            ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

Kube-monkey values set as below,

```
helm get values my-kubemonkey -n chaostesting
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
config:
  debug:
    enabled: true
    schedule_immediate_kill: true
  dryRun: false
  whitelistedNamespaces:
  - default
  - chaostesting
```

Kube-monkey logs shows,

```
       ********** Today's schedule **********
No terminations scheduled
        ********** End of schedule **********
I1008 23:36:32.164182       1 schedule.go:57] Status Update: 0 terminations scheduled today
I1008 23:36:32.164214       1 kubemonkey.go:62] Status Update: Waiting to run scheduled terminations.
I1008 23:36:32.164221       1 kubemonkey.go:76] Status Update: All terminations done.
I1008 23:36:32.164289       1 kubemonkey.go:19] Debug mode detected!
I1008 23:36:32.164294       1 kubemonkey.go:20] Status Update: Generating next schedule in 30 sec
I1008 23:37:02.164430       1 schedule.go:64] Status Update: Generating schedule for terminations
```

I dont see the nginx pods being terminated. Not sure what could be the issue.
Anyone let me know what I am missing..

Comment: any help on this ?

Comment: this configuration is totally fine have you configured runHour: 0 startHour: 1 endHour: 22 and your timezone also?